# Is there a way to get place's email address using facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to get place's email address to my application, I saw that is possible to can get user's email address using Facebook Graph Api, but I couldn't get it searching for place.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You’d need to go from the place id to the associated `page` first, and then request the `emails` field of that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm going to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was exactly what [04FS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10955263/04fs) said, I get the page and then request the email